# d3 dragging not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, drag

I have made a script, which allows me to drag a circle in an svg element.
I have a blue ball which is draggable, but when i drag to the right the ball isn't following the mouse. Instead it jumps in front of the mouse.
Also i have a red ball, which i'd like to follow the blue ball when it's being dragged around with an elastic motion.
**JsFiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/qnhey17f/1/

Code(Html):

```
<!-- I had to add the g element, because the other circle wouldn't display otherwise -->
<svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: lightgrey; border: 1px solid black;">
    <g>
        <circle class="dragCircle" cx="50" cy="50" fill="blue" r="30" cursor="pointer">
    </g>
    <circle cx="50" cy="150" fill="red" r="30" cursor="pointer">
</svg>
```

Code(Js):

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", dragMovement);
function dragMovement(d)
{
    var dX = d3.event.x;
    var dY = d3.event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + dX + ", " + dY + ")");
}
d3.select(".dragCircle").call(drag);
```

Comment: what do you mean by elastic motion and what have you tried in regards to that specific functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/qnhey17f/3/ as for the position of mouse and the blue ball:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", dragMovement);
function dragMovement(d)
{
    var dX = d3.event.x - 50; // subtract cx
    var dY = d3.event.y - 50; // subtract cy
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + dX + ", " + dY + ")");
}
d3.select(".dragCircle").call(drag);
```

Comment: It doesn't work if i add a second circle, the second circle will not be dragged any better.

Comment: I solved the problem myself, the cx and cy attributes were causing the problem, so i'm using transform translate instead.

Comment: Great. Consider adding your final solution as your own answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
<svg>
<circle class="dragCircle" transform="translate(50, 50)" fill="blue" r="30" cursor="pointer">
</svg>
```